# Determination of cut-off point for a therapeutic intervention in clinical trial?

Tags: r, clinical-trials

I have a database from a clinical trial. I'm using R to analyse it.Among others, it contains few continuous variables (let's say x1, x2, ... - these are parameters taken from patients prior to enrollment into study), a dichotomized variable indicating 30-days mortality and dichotomized variable that indicates whether patient had a terapeutic intervention. Here's an example:

| x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 | 30-days mortality | intervention |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.3 | 1.6 | 0.5 | 8.2 | 1 | 0 |
| 1.2 | 5.7 | 3.6 | 9.1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0.8 | 8.2 | 0.8 | 7.1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3.6 | 9.1 | 2.1 | 7.3 | 0 | 1 |

What I need is to determine cut-off point for continuous variables, for which therapeutic intervention significantly decreases mortality. So far, I've used ROC curve to determine cut-off point for x1 in terms of mortality. Then I divided patients into two groups: with x1 > cut-off point and x1 < cut-off point. For each group I performed logistic regression analysis and obtained significant reduction of mortality after intervention in group with "high x1".
Is such approach sufficient to show that for patient with x1 higher than certain value a therapeutic intervention could reduce risk of death? (probably not, therefore how can I do that?)

My second problem is that some of continuous variables are correlated. Therefore, I suppose that if one can be used as a determinant for benefits from intervention, so as variables correlated with it. Is there a way to find "the best one"?